# Why SQL Server CE does not recognize DB when my app is deployed

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server-ce

I am struggling with how to make my app work when deployed - it keeps saying the file is invalid no matter what I do:
What I have now is:

> Data Source="\MyDb.sdf"

The DB should be in the directory where the executable is located.

Comment: That is a relative path, does `MyDb.sdf` exist in the application directory?

Comment: Yes, it does and I would like to have it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to use an absolute path to access the file.

```
var pathToExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
var pathToDb = Path.Combine(path, "MyDb.sdf");
```

`pathToDb` should now be an absolute path to your database object, assuming it is always in the directory of the executing assembly.

Comment: Hmm in the exception, it shows the correct path but still says that the path is invalid.

Comment: I hate to ask again, but you're absolutely sure that the file `MyDb.sdf` explicitly exists in the path?

Comment: Oh, actually your code returns the folder AND the exe file so the output us XX.exe\\MyDb.sdf

Comment: I updated the answer, I forgot that .Location returned the full path to the assembly.  That update should fix it to remove the `XX.exe`.